# Magento 2: How to display multiple prices for same product?

Tags: magento2, price, catalog, custom-options, multiple

I would like to display multiple prices for the same product and customer can select any one of the product price and place an order. But as per my understanding I think this is not achievable by default in Magento. I am searching this in online for a solution but not getting related to this.

Can anyone of you please guide me how to achieve this in Magento 2. Also is there any extensions available in marketplace related to this, please let me know.

Your help will be appreciated.

Looking forward for the solution.

Comment: Yes, It is not achievable in default Magento 2. What you can do that create a configurable product and assign different prices to different variations of the product. Try it.

Comment: Ot you can add custom options too with price

Comment: @JasvirSingh Yes I tried but the thing is that it will create separate sku's for each variations. I am looking for having the multiple prices for same sku.

Comment: @GohilRajesh Yes, I have tried this as well and it's near to my requirement. But when I add the prices as a custom options, its adding the custom option price with base price. Example: Product base price is $50 and Custom option price is $20. When I select the custom option the total price is $50 + $20 but is there any possibility to have custom option price without adding it to base price. Please suggest.

Comment: Then your main product price should be zero.. and you can add main price to custom options directly.